# Type Confusion in v13.1.0

Tags: data-types, version-13.1

Below is an expression that (for me) evaluates differently on the two most recent versions of Mathematica. Can others confirm this? It’s either a bug in v13.1.0, or my installation is faulty (which I doubt). Note: I’m running on Apple Silicon; YMMV on other processors.

```
Row[{First[Map[AbsoluteTime[FileDate[#]]&, {FileNames[][[1]]}]], "   ", $Version}]
```

In both cases, the first item in the Row is a recent date expressed in seconds since the start of the last century; v13.0.1 returns it as an Integer and v13.1.0 returns it as a Real.

Earlier this month, I posted a query entitled "*Function returns a list of 3 integers in v13.0.1, but raises an error in v13.1.0 by returning a list of length 5*"; I was criticized (correctly) for not providing sample code, and I deleted my query as suggested. After severe pruning of the notebook (over half a megabyte in size), I believe I have found the malfunction's source, and have condensed it into a one-liner. I think the above expression will run in any notebook in any folder.

Comment: You can simplify this further to `Head@ AbsoluteTime@ FileDate@ First@ FileNames[]`. I can confirm that MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64 returns `Integer` and version 13.1.0 on Linux x86-64 (the cloud) returns `Real`.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of trials, the difference is how `AbsoluteTime` interprets a `DateObject` containing machine-precision numbers.

On my laptop running **MMA 12.3.1** on Win10-64, the two following expressions both return an integer:

```
AbsoluteTime@ DateObject[{2021, 12, 3, 12, 22, 57.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]
AbsoluteTime@ DateObject[{2021, 12, 3, 12, 22, 57}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]

(* 3847522977 for both *)
```

Note that the only difference is in the seconds specification: the first being machine-precision, the second being an exact number.

---

On the cloud, running **MMA 13.1.0** for Linux x86 (64-bit), the two expressions return different results:

```
AbsoluteTime@ DateObject[{2021, 12, 3, 12, 22, 57.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]
(* Out: 3.84752*^9 *)

AbsoluteTime@ DateObject[{2021, 12, 3, 12, 22, 57}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.] 
(* Out: 3847522977 *)
```

---

The result on the newer version seems more consistent with its input, to be honest. In either case, I was unable to find an indication in the docs on whether `AbsoluteTime` has been recently updated, or what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: Depending on its argument, it seems AbsoluteTime (on either version) sometimes returns an Integer, sometimes a Real. I see no reason for the inconsistency.

Comment: @JamesStein I would expect functions in MMA to behave that way though: `Sin[0]` returns `0`, an `Integer`; whereas `Sin[0.]` returns `0.`, a `Real`. It is perhaps the fact that `FileDate` returns a machine-precision `DateObject` that is more unexpected to me.

Comment: Seeing no reason for the inconsistency doesn't necessarily mean it's a bug. The documentation makes several comments about precision and representation being system dependent. The only guarantee I see is "AbsoluteTime[] is always accurate down to a granularity of $TimeUnit seconds...". It even explicitly says "Noninteger values of d, h, m, s can also be used". So, I think assuming that it'll always be an Integer or always a Real is inappropriate.

Comment: It seems to me that this is more attributable to a change in the behavior of `DateObject`, rather than to a change in `AbsoluteTime`.